# Find the lower bound of $P(-1 < X < 1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

We are given the following:

$X$ is a continous RV

$E[X] = 0$

$E[X^2] = \frac{1}{4}$

Thus we also know $X$ is symmetric around $0$.

We are tasked to find the lower bound of $P(-1 < X < 1)$

Now using Chebyshev's inequality, I was doing the following:

$P(Error < a) > 1 - \frac{Var(Y)}{a^2}$

= $P(Error < a) > 1 - \frac{E[X^2] - E[X]}{a^2} = 1- \frac{\frac{1}{4} - 0}{a^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{4a^2}$

Now I'm unsure as to how I can use $-1 < X < 1$ here in order to compute the final result. What should I plug for $a$ and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the form of Chebyshev's inequality found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Statement).

Because $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{4}$, you have that $\sigma = 0.5$.  Then it's just an application of the inequality in the case that $k = 2$, giving an answer of 3/4.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: Maybe a more direct answer using the version of the inequality you had in the question is that $\textrm{Error} \equiv |X-\mu|$, so you can choose $a=1$ and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

By Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X| > k) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)}{k^p},
$$
for any $p>0$.

Since we have $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X| > k) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(|X|^2)}{k^2},
$$
and since $\mathbb{P}(-1<X<1) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(|X| > 1)$,
substituting $k=1$ yields the desired lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

P(any random variable being within k standard deviations of its mean) $\geq 1-1/k^2$.

The variance is $1/4$, the standard deviation is $1/2$ and the error is $1$, which makes it $2$ standard deviations out.  So $k=2$ in the formula and you get $1-1/2^2 = 3/4$.